# How to align the image on the left of the article (beside it) rather than being on top

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm following a flask tutorial and trying to make it so that the profile picture is displayed in each article of the website, so I have this code to display an article

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<article class="media content-section">
  <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">

  <div class="media-body">
    <div class="article-metadata">
      <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ post.author.username }}</a>
      <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}</small>
    </div>

    <h2><a class="article-title" href="{{ url_for('post', post_id=post.id) }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>

    <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
  </div>
</article>

<article class="media content-section">
  <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">

  <div class="media-body">
    <div class="article-metadata">
      <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ post.author.username }}</a>
      <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}</small>
    </div>

    <h2><a class="article-title" href="{{ url_for('post', post_id=post.id) }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>

    <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
  </div>
</article>
```

But instead of displaying it like this:

[image: Corey Shafer Image]

It instead shows it like this:

[image: Bingus Image]

This is the css code for the page:

```
body {
  background: #fafafa;
  color: #333333;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  color: #444444;
}

.bg-steel {
  background-color: #5f788a;
}

.site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #cbd5db;
}

.site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.content-section {
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.article-title {
  color: #444444;
}

a.article-title:hover {
  color: #428bca;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.article-content {
  white-space: pre-line;
}

.article-img {
  height: 65px;
  width: 65px;
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.article-metadata {
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3
}

.article-metadata a:hover {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.article-svg {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.account-img {
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.account-heading {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
```

I hope anyone can help me in solving this minor inconvenience!

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version (per the instructions in the tag you used) so we can help you properly.

Comment: I've converted your code to a functioning snippet. It doesn't display like your image shows. Please edit further to demonstrate the problem. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: did you ever figure this issue out? I am also watching this video tutorial ! its a good one :) and I know the issues are due to the bootstrap code. I too am having issues with the blog portion of this page.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running the code in question and it worked for me as per expected result. Added a snippet below.

```css
body {
  background: #fafafa;
  color: #333333;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  color: #444444;
}

.bg-steel {
  background-color: #5f788a;
}

.site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #cbd5db;
}

.site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.content-section {
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.article-title {
  color: #444444;
}

a.article-title:hover {
  color: #428bca;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.article-content {
  white-space: pre-line;
}

.article-img {
  height: 65px;
  width: 65px;
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.article-metadata {
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3
}

.article-metadata a:hover {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.article-svg {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.account-img {
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.account-heading {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <article class="media content-section">
    <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">

    <div class="media-body">
      <div class="article-metadata">
        <a class="mr-2" href="#">Author 1</a>
        <small class="text-muted">29-June-2021</small>
      </div>

      <h2><a class="article-title" href="{{ url_for('post', post_id=post.id) }}">Post 1</a></h2>

      <p class="article-content">Post 1 Post 1 Post 1</p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article class="media content-section">
    <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">

    <div class="media-body">
      <div class="article-metadata">
        <a class="mr-2" href="#">Author 2</a>
        <small class="text-muted">29-June-2021</small>
      </div>

      <h2><a class="article-title" href="{{ url_for('post', post_id=post.id) }}">Post 2</a></h2>

      <p class="article-content">Post 2 Post 2 Post 2 Post 2</p>
    </div>
  </article>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question, which asks for a _horizontal_ orientation (and which the code given already provides).

Answer (score -1):

add to your css

```
.article-img {
float:left;
}
.media-body {
float:right;
}
```

Comment: Please take the [tour]. We're not a discussion forum and answers are expected to be more specific.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.